# Tmux and Iterm2 -- Performance

Tags: tmux, iterm2, iterm, tmuxinator

I am using tmux, tmuxinator, and iTerm2. I'm passing the -CC command to my tmux so that I get "native" iTerm windows. Problem is I'm having noticeable performance problems just typing in the command line.

I'm guessing this is because iterm is relaying info back to tmux. Has anyone had this problem or found solutions to this problem?

Comment: Which version of iTerm2 are you using? IME the latest beta/release candidate has much improved performance over the current production release.

Comment: @TimoGeusch i'm using `Build 2.9.20160313` for iTerm